# Problems with images in slideshow. jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, frontend

I am trying to create a responsive slideshow but I have problem with percentage and the slideshow shows two images at the same time.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/7B8Bb/3/

Answer (score 0):

Try [FlexSlider](http://flex.madebymufffin.com/), a jQuery based responsive slider plugin.